# Download file through REST web service and javascript or angular code

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, rest, download

I have to call a REST web service from javascript (with `Ajax`, `JQuery` or `AngularJs`) that provides a file download. This controller use a `HttpServletResponse` to send the file.
The file is created (not write into file system) in the download method (so create and send the file) so at the start of the procedure I show up a waiting bar that I have to hide at the end of download.
With the `th:href` into `a` tag the download works fine but how can I show and hide the wiating bar?
This is the modal code:

```
<!-- Modal confirm export RDI -->
<div class="modal" id="rdiExportModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Export RDI</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="box-body">Do you want to export an Excel file of this RDI table?</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left"
                    data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a th:href="@{excel/{idCar}(idCar=${idCar})}"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" 
                    id="exportRdiButton">OK</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

The  web services should be like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "excel/"+document.getElementById("hiddenIdCar").value,
        beforeSend: function() {
            waitingModal.showPleaseWait();
        },
        success: function(data,status,xhr){
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,e){
            window.location.href = "/500";
        }   
    }).complete(function() {
        waitingModal.hidePleaseWait();
    });
```

but doesn't work, it doesn't download the file, and I don't find any advice to implement this code. Do you know some solution?Thanks

UPDATE: has workaroud I test with success:

```
waitingModal.showPleaseWait();
var a = document.getElementById('exportRdiButton'); //or grab it by tagname etc
a.href = "excel/"+document.getElementById("hiddenIdCar").value;
window.location=a.href;
$('#rdiExportModal').modal('hide');
waitingModal.hidePleaseWait();
```

Comment: sorry, iit doesn't download the file

Comment: did you try saving the file in the `success` function callback?

Comment: but I don't have the path, the file isn't stored

Comment: if the URL you're requesting is correct and the it actually returns a file, then it should be accessible in the `success` function.

Comment: try doing this `success: function(data,status,xhr) { console.log(data); }` and see what it returns

Comment: I find a partial workaround like main post. It return the data of file